# Quartz2D: How to convert a clipping rect to an inverted mask at runtime?

Tags: ios, macos, quartz-2d, cgcontext

Given:

1. a CGContextRef (`ctx`) with frame `{0,0,100,100}`
2. and a rect (`r`), with frame `{25,25,50,50}`

It's easy to clip the context to that rect:

```
CGContextClipToRect(ctx, r);
```

to mask out the red area below *(red == mask)*:

[image]

But I want to **invert** this clipping rect to convert it into a clipping **mask**. The desired outcome is to mask the red portion below *(red == mask)*:

[image]

I want to do this programmatically at runtime.

I **do not** want to manually prepare a bitmap image to ship statically with my app.

Given `ctx` and `r`, how can this be done at runtime most easily/straightforwardly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read about fill rules in the [“Filling a Path” section of the *Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106).

In your case, the easiest thing to do is use the even-odd fill rule.  Create a path consisting of your small rectangle, and a much larger rectangle:

```
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectMake(25,25,50,50));
CGContextAddRect(ctx, CGRectInfinite);
```

Then, intersect this path into the clipping path using the even-odd fill rule:

```
CGContextEOClip(ctx);
```

Comment: Yep, perfect. I knew there must be a way. Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 3):

You could clip the context with `CGContextClipToRects()` by passing rects that make up the red frame you've wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid this may be the simplest solution. But I was hoping there was something more elegant/simple that I was overlooking. For the rectangle case, your suggestion works fairly easily. But given a path, your solution wouldn't work. That made me think there must be a better solution available in Quartz2D somewhere…

Comment: Then you could use CGContextClipToMask() and draw your border/frame in an UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do all your painting as normal, and then do:

```
CGContextClearRect(ctx, r);
```

after everything has been done?

Comment: It seems like that should work, but `CGContextClearRect()` always just does a "fill with black" in the given rect (which I've never understood). So, no I don't think this works.

Comment: `CGContextClearRect` sets all components of each pixel to zero.  If your context has an alpha channel, each pixel becomes clear.  Otherwise, each pixel becomes black.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful extension for implementing rob's answer

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    func addClipInverse() {
        let paths = UIBezierPath()
        paths.append(self)
        paths.append(.init(rect: .infinite))
        paths.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        paths.addClip()
    }
}
```